# mvc 5 Pass textbox value as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, textbox

This is my view:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("SearchParameter", null, new { @style = "width:200px; height:30px" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("GetSearchParameter", "Parameter", new { sSearchParameterValue = ??? }, FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="GO!" />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my Controller "Parameter" I have a method "GetSearchParameter" that has one parameter which is "sSearchParameterValue". What I would like to do is pass the value of my textbox to that parameter.

I already tried two different ways:

1) I get sSearchParameterValue = null:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSearchParameter", "Parameter", new { sSearchParameterValue = Request.Form["SearchParameter"] }, FormMethod.Post))
```

2) I get *A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client*:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetSearchParameter", "Parameter", new { sSearchParameterValue = @Html.TextBox("SearchParameter") }, FormMethod.Post))
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thank you,

Grega

Comment: Your input needs to be inside the `<form>`

Comment: Do you mean just the input or the entire table ?

Comment: The `<table>` needs to be inside the `<form>` otherwise it would be invalid html. But why are you using a <table>? A `<table>` is for tabular data, and should never be used for layout.

Comment: If I put <table> inside <form> I get this: error CS0103: The name 'sSearchParameterValue' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You have to remove `new { sSearchParameterValue = .... }`

Comment: But again, why do you have a `<table>` Do NOT use tables for layout!!

Comment: I don't understand. Don't I need new { sSearchParameterValue = .... } to pass a parameter to my controller method.

Comment: No of course not - your form posts the name/value pairs of its successful form controls (and `@Html.BeginForm` is server side code - its generated in the server before its sent to the view so adding a route parameter posts back the value that was generated on the server (it does not magically change based on the value of an input)

Comment: Thank you. I got rid of <table> and did <input type="submit" value="GO!" formmethod="post" formaction="GetSearchParameter" />
 and it works :)

Comment: You do not need the `formmethod` and `formaction` attributes in the input if the input is inside @using (Html.BeginForm("GetSearchParameter", "Parameter") { .... }

Comment: OK thank you. I am not using Html.BeginForm anymore. But can you tell me what is better practice, using Html.BeginForm or not ?

Comment: That's up to you :)